# Google Analytics alwaysSendReferrer field, but i want to send info only from few domains, how?

Tags: google-analytics

I have few domains with various purpose (production, development, testing) and i have pasted there the same google analytics script. I don't care from which domain i will get data, it's important to me to have it all in one place... BUT i have my vagrant virtual development machine too and it has got a much longer loading times, and i don't want situation when my development environment, where i spent more time than on the anothers, messes up my analytics statistics.

To sum it up: Is there any option to set filter or to send google analytics data only from certain pages?

Thank You :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, if You use php You can simply put Your analytics script in:

```
<?php
        if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']!='your_excluded_domain')
        {
            echo 'your analytics script';
        }
?>
```